# C++ project compilation forcing the option /clr though executing it with no Common Language Runtime support

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr

I have a CLI/C++ project in which I removed the code in .NET and left only the code in C++. Though I already switched off the option /clr from the project by selecting **No Common Language Runtime support**, during compilation the code throws the error:

```
Command line error D8016 : '/EHs' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible
```

In addition, the log file generated during the compilation shows:

```
...
...
/FD /EHsc /MTd /Fo"C:\Users\Ende\Desktop\Slot2008\build\Debug\\" /Fd"C:\Users\Ende\Desktop\Slot2008\build\Debug\\vc90.pdb"
/W3 /c /Zi /clr /TP /wd4945 .\MAIN.cpp
```

So, one way or another, VC++ is forcing the compilation with the option /clr though it is off. Thanks in advance for any explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those into this question, the answer is that you might try many advices on the internet related to adjusting the compilation options. If nothing works which is likely (trust me config files tend to get messy), I advise you to create a new Win32 project and put all your sources into this project.